# Sending firebase database data to client through cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send data from my firebase database back to my client in a cloud function. I want to return the entire json child object. Here is the code for my cloud function:

```
exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
 admin.database().ref('store/ingredients').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    
    return snapshot.val();

  });

});
```

Here is my client code that is invoking this cloud function and accessing its data:

```
const addNumbers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addNumbers');
  addNumbers().then(result => {
    console.log(result.data + "in client");
  });
```

But the data returned in the client is null and the cloud function is returning only object [Object] in the firebase logs. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to return something from the top-level code in your Cloud Function.

The easiest way is to use a `then` clause:

```
exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.database().ref('store/ingredients').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
});
```

Now the value from the database "bubbles up" to the calling code, and is then returned out of your function as a promise.

---

On modern JavaScript versions, you can make this code easier to read by using `async`/`await`:

```
exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  let snapshot = await admin.database().ref('store/ingredients').once('value')
  return snapshot.val();
});
```

This works exactly the same under the hood (it's really just syntactic sugar), but most developers find it much easier to read.

Comment: That helped a little bit, I was able to get the data returned in the client. However, it is still showing as [object Object]in client, and so I think this means it is still not able to get the full json object of the children nested under this path, if I specify a path to the innermost child, I am getting the value. but I want to input this broader path and get the entire json child as my return value

Comment: You're probably getting the data, but not printing it correctly. Try `console.log(result.data)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data) + "in client");`

Comment: JSON.stringify printed the data, is there a way to keep the data as a JSON so I can perform JSON actions on it later?

Comment: You already can: if you return a JSON object from a callable Cloud Function, it will show up as a JSON object in your client too. You just can't log it the way you tried to do, which is why I showed you how to convert it to a string. But you should already be able to get the properties in the code, like `console.log(result.data.childProperty)`.